# Navigate to URL with additional header

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway we can navigate (via `<a/>` click) to a URL with additional header in the request ? here's my code :

i have an `<a href="#" id="aUsers"/>` tag, and then i handle the `onClick()` event via JQuery :

```
$('#aUsers').click(function () {
  var spAuthData = sessionStorage.getItem('sp-auth-data');
  window.location.href = '/users.html?sp-auth-data' = spAuthData;
});
```

I want to put the `spAuthData` value in the `authorization` header, so i can have a clean URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to manipulate HTTP headers with a plain url.

You can use `headers` parameter of jQuery AJAX request if it is suitable in your situation. For example, you can update the contents of some `div`s with AJAX HTML response.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/users.html',
    headers: { 'Authorization': spAuthData }
}).done(function() 
{
});
```

Otherwise, it looks like you need to make some server-side changes.

But why don't you use cookies or something like this?
`Authorization` is used only by unauthorized users during authorization. In my opinion, sending this header on every request from the browser manually sounds bad. The best approach is to send this header once during authorization, create a user session and store it in cookies (as an access-token, forms ticket or whatever else).

Comment: Thanks for your information. The `spAuthData` is actually some sort of token resulted from authorization process, i stored its value in session storage and i'm thinking about attaching this value using `authorization` header : `Authorization: 'token ' + spAuthData` (well that's just a made-up) in every request. If it's not possible i'll consider using Cookie or just stick with the query string. Thanks again