# Blazor navigation with authorization header and bearer token

Tags: c#, routes, navigation, authorization, blazor

I want to create HealthChecks portal via [HealthChecksUI](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks) but with limited access with authorization.
Also I using **Blazor** to accomplish authorization dialog creation and receiving access token.

So I configuring HealthChecksUI:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //...
    app.UseEndpoints(endpointsBuilder =>
    {
        //...
        endpointsBuilder.MapHealthChecksUI(setup =>
        {
            setup.UIPath = "/portal";
            setup.ApiPath = "/portal/api";
            setup.WebhookPath = "/portal/webhooks";
            setup.ResourcesPath = "/portal/resources";
        }).RequireAuthorization(); // This means access to '/portal' route will be limited by authorization.
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

I using **bearer token** in **HTTP Authorization header** for authorization while performing any request.

Next let's check authorization work:
GET request from **POSTMAN** with valid bearer token to '/portal' route passing successfully. Also, if I change token then I recieve 401 Unauthorized error. So it's seems authorization system working correctly.

Next step will be using authorization dialog to perform token receiving and redirecting to portal page.
*Code below it's just a simple authorize function using in .razor page*

```cs
private async Task SubmitAsync()
{
    var (authorizationSuccessful, accessToken) = await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(authorizationData).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (authorizationSuccessful)
    {
        navigationManager.NavigateTo("/portal", true);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Incorrect login or password");
    }
}
```

So problem is:
When authorization passing (`authorizationSuccessful` is `true`) and navigation performing, I get to '/portal' page without any authorization data, so I get 401 Unauthorized error.

#### The question is:

How can I pass received bearer token (`accessToken`) through `NavigateTo` method in `Authorization` HTTP Header to accomplish authorized access to '/portal' page? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's **not possible** to accomplish this task that way.

According to tries to do something like this using JS only ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307721/redirect-to-url-with-auth-header) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430939/navigate-to-url-with-additional-header)), it can't be done with plain JS.

So we have just few options here:

#### Share authorization token through cookies

Cookies are browser-based shared storage, so check access token from here possible right after navigation.

#### Send authorization token through query

`NavigateTo` method can be used with query parameters like this:

```cs
navigationManager.NavigateTo($"/portal?token={accessToken}", true);
```

So we can check access token from query parameters directly.